# Docker with wordpress/mysql/nginx, no styles in wordpress

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, docker-compose

So I'm trying to configure few containers with `docker-compose`. My goal being to use nginx to run wordpress-fpm. So far here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        links:
            - wordpress
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./nginx_config_content:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
        restart: always

    wordpress:
        image: wordpress:4.9.2-php7.0-fpm
        links:
            - wp_db:mysql
        volumes:
            - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "aqwe123"
        restart: always

    wp_db:
        image: mariadb
        volumes:
            - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "aqwe123"
        restart: always
```

And my nginx `wordpress.conf`:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name test.io;

       root /var/www/html;
       index index.php;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       }
}
```

Everything connects together flawlessly but when I open the website from another computer on `http://192.168.1.161` I get this:

[image: wordpress]

Wordpress but with no styles. I checked the page source code and I can see the css points to a valid paths like `<link rel='stylesheet' id='install-css'  href='http://192.168.1.161/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />` and following the link works, the css file does exist.
I've been trying to solve this for hours, I suspect the nginx config file is missing something but I can't find what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this outside of your server block:

```
http { 
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

It should successfully load in the files needed to present the view.

Comment: It doesn't work I still have the same issue. Here is the whole script: https://paste.ofcode.org/3bM2er5hHM7qymqrd7WvrEr

Comment: Maybe put it in the location https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875443/185316

Comment: Still having the same issue :(

Comment: Oh gosh actually it worked after clearing my cache. Thanks a lot!